# Seperation of streetname and housenumber for American Streetnames and other

Tags: c#, street-address

A month ago I asked how you can seperate the housenumber and the street of common adresses.
This question was answered with an very good answer. The solution ist below.

```
private static (string street, string number) SplitStreet(string value)
    {
        var match = Regex.Match(value, @"\p{L}{2,}(?:\s\p{L}+)*");

        string street = match.Value;

        string number = (match.Index > 0)
          ? value.Substring(0, match.Index)
          : value.Substring(match.Index + match.Length);

        return (street, number.Trim());
    }
```

Now the problem is this function can´t seperate an street which looks like this:

- Ernst-Thälmannstrasse 8
- 203 East 50th St.

I tried my best but can´t find an solution for this problem.
Maybe i didnt used the right pattern for the two examples.

Anybody who got the same problem and found an solution?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Gonna be very difficult because there are so many ways of entering the information. You should try to get the data separated before it's entered

Comment: I agree with @Charlieface. There are _way_ too many ways to enter that information. The only way I can see this happening is _if_ you have house number either at the start or at the end you could try `^(\d+)?([ ]+)?(.*)([ ]+)?(\d+)?$`. Note: this is not a final regex. There is no point in trying to come up with final regex unless you can specify _all_ cases. That way we can be sure it won't fail at least for all the cases being considered _at thispoint_.